# Python how to split a data frame into two equal sized groups based on unique customer IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, split, dataframe

I have a data frame of transactions with customer IDs that looks like the following

```
ID
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
4
```

I want to **randomly** divide this data set into 2 other datasets (`data1` and `data2` which have the **same number of unique IDs**. It is important that the split is random. The output can be as follows

For `data1`:

```
ID
2
2
4
4
```

For `data2`:

```
ID
1
1
1
3
3
3
3
```

How can I do this in python/pandas easily?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the unique ids in a list and split the list in 2 halves:

```
In [28]: import random

In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
    ID
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    3
9    4
10   4

In [32]: ids = df.ID.unique()

In [33]: random.shuffle(ids)

In [34]: n = len(ids)

In [35]: ids1, ids2 = ids[:n/2], ids[n/2:]

In [36]: ids1
Out[36]: array([1, 2])

In [37]: ids2
Out[37]: array([3, 4])

In [39]: df1 = df[df.ID.isin(ids1)]

In [40]: df2 = df[df.ID.isin(ids2)]

In [41]: df1
Out[41]: 
   ID
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2

In [42]: df2
Out[42]: 
    ID
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    3
9    4
10   4
```

Comment: This doesn't result in 2 **Random** data frames. My data is ordered, so following this method would result in two ordered data sets.

Comment: You can shuffle the `ids` list. I'll update my answer.